# Why TAB inside VIM moves one space after exactly three-long characters words?

Tags: vim, tabstop

After one-character length word or more than three-length characters word there TAB moves exactly 4 spaces. 
My .vimrc configuration file is it as it follows.

```
syntax on

" number of spaces moved along by pressing >>, << or ==
set shiftwidth=4

" number of spaces moved along by pressing the <TAB> or <BS> key
set softtabstop=4

set expandtab
```

The tabstop configuration value is set to default, 8. 
I was expecting that TAB will move forward 4 spaces no matter what.

Comment: Can you show examples? Your description is not very clear.

Comment: Also you do not show the value of `tabstop`. Is it set to the default (8)?

Comment: It happens with me as well and my `tabstop` is set to default(8)

Answer (score 2):

When indenting, vim inserts however many spaces it needs to get to the next multiple of `shiftwidth`.

In your case, `shiftwidth=4`, so vim inserts spaces until it gets to column 4: only one space.

If you want vim to instead blindly insert four spaces *no matter what*, try the following in your vimrc:

```
inoremap <TAB> <space><space><space><space>
```

That will make vim insert 4 spaces.

Comment: Actually that will insert 7 spaces, because there are 3 spaces in between the `<space>` references...